# Get json error when calling from angular with zend framework 1

Tags: json, angularjs, zend-framework

My code in zend action is as follow:

```
$this->getResponse()
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
$result = array("status" => true, "result" => $output);
        $json = json_encode($result);
echo $json;
```

And My angular controller is as follow:

```
app.controller("statController", function($scope, $http){
        $http.get("mydomain/controller/action/")
        .success(function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        }).error(function(response) {
                alert(response)
            console.log('Error : ' + response);
        });
});
```

When I call the url from the browser and inspect it in the Network tab the result is in json.
But when I inspect it from my angular call, the result has this error:

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data
```

Also the url I call (the zend controller and action) is not in the same domain as my angular.js code. I use Zend Framework 1.

**UPDATE**
I found the prblem. I was trying to access from different domain so I only needed to add

```
$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
```

To my action.

Comment: try:678941
$this->getHelper('Layout')
         ->disableLayout();

    $this->getHelper('ViewRenderer')
         ->setNoRender();
$this->getResponse()
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
$result = array("status" => true, "result" => $output);
        $json = json_encode($result, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo $json; exit; For more detail:- http://se2.php.net/json_encode

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code at your action,

```
public function yourAction()
{
    // Disable the layout and view for the action
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

    // Set the header as JSON
    header("Content-Type:application/json");

    // Your code starts here
    // .........................
    $result = array("status" => true, "result" => $output);
    $json = json_encode($result);

    echo Zend_Json::encode($json);
}
```

Note: Code is not tested. Try it once, may be its the issue with your layout or something.

Comment: Thank you. For the reply, those didn't help. I found the fix by adding '$this->getResponse()->setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');' to my controller since I was trying to access from different domain.